Passkeys Registration and Login Flow Not Working on Android - Google Password Manager Issue
I'm currently implementing passkeys for user authentication in my web application. The passkey registration and login flow works perfectly on iOS and Windows. However, I'm encountering an issue on Android where the Google Password Manager does not seem to save the passkey or credentials.
The Registration Flow works fine and reports successfully on android devices like pixel and other android phones but when trying to login using that device it gives no passkey found error, on checking we can see that there are no passkeys but the registration doesn't give any error and the response provides all the data.
I've checked that the origins and other configurations seem correct, as the flow works on other platforms. I'm unsure why Android, specifically the Google Password Manager, isn't handling the passkey storage correctly.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with passkeys on Android?
What could be causing the Google Password Manager to not save the credentials?
Are there any specific configurations required for Android that I'm missing?
I have debugged the issue and confirmed that the passkey or credential is not being saved on Android devices, which is causing the registration and login process to fail. Below is the relevant portion of my configuration:
"fido2": {
  "serverDomain": "localhost",  
  "serverName": "FIDO",
  "origins": [ "https://localhost:4200/" ], 
  "timestampDriftTolerance": 300000,
  "backupEligibleCredentialPolicy": "allowed",
  "backedUpCredentialPolicy": "allowed"
}

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
